# Not able to run file in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

i am using python spyder 2.7.
i encountered a warning stating :

" no Python shell is currently selected to run eg.py
Please select or open a new python interpreter and try again"

Comment: Show some code, commands, etc., so others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'Consoles'-->'Open a Python Console' in the menu bar. That should open the console for you which will let you run the code.
Alternatively, you can use the shortcut key Alt+o+p.